# Construct matrix from elements of structure

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have to solve some equation during my computation. I achieve this by

```
W1 = solve(zero);
```

where `zero` is something like this

```
[ w1_1*w2_1 + w1_2*w2_2, w2_1^2 + w2_2^2 - 1, w2_1*w3_1 + w2_2*w3_2]
[ w1_1*(w1_1 + w3_1) + w1_2*(w1_2 + w3_2) - 1, w2_1*(w1_1 + w3_1) + w2_2*(w1_2 + w3_2), w3_1*(w1_1 + w3_1) + w3_2*(w1_2 + w3_2) - 1]
```

what i am getting is

```
W1 = 

    w1_1: [4x1 sym]
    w1_2: [4x1 sym]
    w2_1: [4x1 sym]
    w2_2: [4x1 sym]
    w3_1: [4x1 sym]
    w3_2: [4x1 sym]
```

I can access elements of this structure and construct a symbolic matrix:

```
>> W = [W1.w1_1(1) W1.w1_2(1); W1.w2_1(1) W1.w2_2(1); W1.w3_1(1) W1.w3_2(1)]

W =

[ 2^(1/2)/2,  0]
[         0, -1]
[ 2^(1/2)/2,  0]
```

But the problem is: matrix size depends on data and varies from run to run. How can i do this in a more generic way, without explicit adressing of all elements?

Comment: If the matrix size depends on the data, the `solve` depends on the data and the solution size depends on the data, right? What is th eproblem with the size? Do you have dynamic variable names thus `W1.wn_m` are created?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yep, everything is correct. The trouble i'm expierencing is a dynamic access to fields of the structure.

Comment: This is why everyone says that one of the worst ideas in MATLAB is to have dynamic variable names. Consider, instead of solving this, reformatting your code so you do never have dynamic variable names. That would be, without a doubt, the best possible case. Else, look at the very dangerous and frowned upon `eval`

Comment: @AnderBiguri Unfortunately those variables come from `W = sym('w', [a, b]);` so i dont see any way to avoid them. Well, eval seems to be the only option for me.